# To check convergence of series $\sum (-1)^{n}\left(\frac{(n!)e^{n}}{n^{n}}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given series is $\sum (-1)^{n}\left(\frac{(n!)e^{n}}{n^{n}}\right)$.First I try to check whether it is absolutely convergent but it is diverging by logarithmic test.So I try alternating series test but I am not getting whether $\lim a(n)$ is $0$ or not.I try to use the fact that when $\lim \left(\frac {a(n+1)}{a(n)}\right)$$<$$|1|$ then $\lim a(n)$ tends to $0$ but $\lim a(n+1)/a(n)=1$ so it is also inconclusive.So what is the limit of $a(n)$?Is there any other test which will help?

Comment: why don't you use Stirling's approximatation and Abel convergence criteria?

Comment: Sorry but I haven't studied both the things

Comment: Hint : I note your series $(-1)^n a_n$. You have computed $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, and probably found $\frac{e}{(1+1/n)^n}$. Using that $\log(1+x)<x$ for $x>0$ and taking $x=1/n$, show that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>1$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Diesirae92..got it..clearly a(n) is going to diverge by using stirling's approximation